# How to schedule an IOT job in AWS to run at specific time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, iot, job-scheduling, aws-iot

I want to run the device update using aws iot jobs can I set startTime? 
I saw in their documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-iot-device-sdk#examples .
"autoStart: If set to true then agent will execute launch command when agent starts up."
but they didn't mention anything regarding how to schedule the start at specific time

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any feature to set a schedule or introduce a time delay for AWS IoT Jobs.

The `autostart` flag refers to an *offline* device coming *online*, and what behaviour happens then.

You can implement this yourself by having a process running which knows to create the jobs at the correct time.